# Resize chart areas to fit to chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a chart with multiple chart areas. There is also a button that when pressed deletes ( `chart1.ChartAreas.Remove(chart1.ChartAreas[select]);`) a selected chart area, as you can see below :
[image]
How can I resize the other chart Areas in order to take over the free area when one chart area is deleted?

Comment: Did you set the sizes (Positions) ? If so: You need to do that again.

Comment: Yes, but since the number of chart areas is dynamic in my project it is hard to assign specific values. Is there a way to autoscale the areas ?

Comment: Well, the ChartAreas are set to Autoscale by default. When you reset that default, all aspects of their ElementPositions will be reset. Why did you change to a custom ElementPosition ? (Note that ElementPosition includes both size and location, both in percent of the respective containers!!)

Comment: You are right, I had changed the default setting somewhere else in my code. Thanks